# Import XML link from ECB and extract time series

Tags: import, time-series, xml

I would like to extract the time series from a XML link provided by the ECB. Unfortunately, I am not able to extract the data time series. May someone be able to help me please?

I start to import the data by `eurusd=Import["https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange _rates/html/usd.xml", "XML"]`

Now I would like to build a time series using the `OBS_VALUE` out of the `XMLElement`. Hence I try to extract them by using the command `series=eurusd[[All,"OBS_VALUE"]]`. Unfortunately this does not work. Can someone please tell me how I can extract the time series out of the XML data link?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting your link (removing one blanc) the answer to your question can be found with

```
Cases[eurusd, ("OBS_VALUE" -> a_) :> a, Infinity]
```

Comment: Dear @UlrichNeumann thank you very the information! It word very well, great! Is it possible to "restrict" the time period (TIME_PERIOD) also? Let's say for one year from 1999-01-04 to 1999-12-30, or do I need to select the elements afterwards?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to select inside Cases. If you pick `ob = Cases[eurusd, ("OBS_VALUE" -> a_) :> a, Infinity]`, 
`ti = Cases[eurusd, ("TIME_PERIOD" -> a_) :> DateList[ a], Infinity]` you can combine the elements `Transpose[{ob,ti}]` and filter data concerning date.

Comment: Okay, no worries @UlrichNeumann. Thank you again!